# Написание названия населенного пункта

Tags: склонение

Здравствуйте! Пожалуйста, подскажите, как правильно написать:

1. ... о деревне Дворяниново или
2. ... о деревне Дворянинове

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: о деревне Дворяниново

ПРАВИЛО

Русские топонимы при наличии родового наименования обычно склоняются: в городе Москве, на острове Валааме.

Однако названия на ОВО/ЁВО/ЕВО и ИНО/ЫНО имеют особенности. При наличии  родового наименования они не склоняются: в усадьбе Абрамцево, из села Бородино.  При отсутствии родового возможны оба варианта: в Абрамцеве или в Абрамцево, в Бородине или в Бородино, при этом литературным пока считается склоняемый вариант.

Тенденция к несклоняемости этих топонимов при отсутствии родового наименования наметилась в последнее время,  так как при склонении их следует отличать от сходных названий мужского рода на твердый согласный, например: город Пушкино и город Пушкин. Таким образом, не склоняя название, мы обеспечиваем его точность.

Comment: София,только что увидела Ваш ответ... совсем смутилась))). Такие разные мнения. Благодарю за развернутое объяснение! Если Вас не затруднит, могли бы Вы подсказать источник приведенного Вами правила? У меня проблема с написанием названий населенных пунктов. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я пользовалась информацией из Грамматики-80. Но вот еще можно посмотреть полезную книгу "Практическая стилистика современного русского языка". Справочники русского языка. Бельчиков Юлий Абрамович. Там много интересного, ее, кажется, можно скачать или читать в электронном виде.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Здесь уместен будет первый вариант. Если бы Вы писали о населенном пункте, употребляя только его название, то правильно было бы "О Дворянинове", но поскольку Вы уточняете, что это деревня, то оно и становится определяющим словом. То есть, на выходе мы имеем "О деревне Дворяниново".

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

В РУССКОМ языке склоняются все слова, включая названия, личные, иностранные и т.д., НО в бюрократическом русском (то есть по придуманным бюрократами от языка правилам) есть стремление "приблизить" русскую грамматику к западной - несклоняемой. Поэтому есть движение сделать несклоняемыми сначала иностранные слова, затем нерусские женские фамилии, а теперь уже замахнулись и на русскую топонимику. Скоро все названия будут несклоняемыми.

Comment: Слово не склоняется, если при склонении искажается точность названия (в Пушкино - в Пушкине) или это фонетически неудобно: на озере Ильмень. В топографии названия не склоняются. Неужели всё это придумали бюрократы-чиновники?